# Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, duplicates

While adding     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0' i got these errors.

```
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential found in modules firebase-auth-19.2.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.EmailAuthCredential found in modules firebase-auth-19.2.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider found in modules firebase-auth-19.2.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.FacebookAuthCredential found in modules firebase-auth-19.2.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider found in modules firebase-auth-19.2.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthProvider found in modules firebase-auth-19.2.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.GithubAuthCredential found in modules firebase-auth-19.2.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider found in modules firebase-auth-19.2.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthCredential found in modules firebase-auth-19.2.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider found in modules firebase-auth-19.2.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.TwitterAuthCredential found in modules firebase-auth-19.2.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider found in modules firebase-auth-19.2.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.UserInfo found in modules firebase-auth-19.2.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.UserProfileChangeRequest found in modules firebase-auth-19.2.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.UserProfileChangeRequest$Builder found in modules firebase-auth-19.2.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.zza found in modules firebase-auth-19.2.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0) and jetified-firebase-auth-common-9.6.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.6.1)
```

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

Comment: Can you please share your gradles?

Answer (score -1):

check if you added any other dependency which includes firebase, if yes then exclude.

Answer (score -1):

Try bellow change

Just replace bellow tow line with your firebase auth and auth UI dependancy

```
 implementation('com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:x.x.x') {
     exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-auth'
  }

 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
```

Comment: who one downvoted my answer please add the comment so we can take care next time when giving answers.